# Can available -ve supply somehow used for an IC requires positive voltages?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, integrated-circuit, ground

This is a doubt related to a charge sensitive amplifier. Amplifier specification says: Power consumption approx. 80 mA at -20V at 60Ω. Does it mean that the amplifier operates in -20v / GND supply ?. The amplifier has two ICs CA3046 (NPN Transistor array). I have attached their ratings and a link to Data sheet. They need positive voltages in all scenarios. Does a -20v/GND supply provide these +ve voltages?[image]
The link is :[Link to data sheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/235/CA3046-pdf.php)

Unfortunately, I don't have the schematic of the amplifier. I attached the manual of the amplifier as well.[image]

[image]

[image: Schematic diagram]

Comment: Impossible to answer, include the schematic of the amplifier. "3046" is not a proper model type, I guess you mean **LM**3046? If not: include a link to the "3046" datasheet. Regarding positive and negative voltages: it depends what your **reference** is. Take a 9 V battery and a multimeter. Measure with + (of battery) on + (of meter) and - on -, you get 9 V. Now swap the leads, you get -9 V, does that suddenly make this battery unusable in a device that needs +9 V from a 9 V battery?

Comment: https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/235/CA3046-pdf.php

Comment: How about making a "neat" question and changing "3046" to "CA3046" and then making that text a link to the datasheet. Select the text, click the link icon, it is really easy to do.

Comment: I made a schematic from the ´PCB board. It is not perfect.

Comment: You want an answer: you include a schematic. Without a schematic we can only **guess**.

Comment: I added a schematic to the question. As I mentioned, it is not perfect. I wasn't able to identify couple of components (example. one coil). It is an old design from the 1980s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107907/discussion-between-sunny-old-days-and-bimpelrekkie).

Comment: The schematic is indeed "terrible" and not helping much. For example the transistor arrays are drawn as "a box" so you'd have to also look at the pinout to see how the NPNs are connected. If you have a 20 V power supply with an **isolated** output you can use it as a GND / - 20 V supply. Ground is **just a reference** in the end.

Comment: I have a GND / -20v Supply.  My doubt is, how the transistor arrays +ve volt requirements (like Vceo, Vcbo, etc) are satisfied from these GND /-20v Supply.

Comment: It may be that the type of laboratory setup in which such a circuit would be used would use positive ground and/or -60V was a standard supply for that kind of (very VERY specialized) equipment.